# My docker environment on airflow cannot find one of the system package installed

Tags: python, docker, selenium, firefox, airflow

[link to the code] https://github.com/Rafouf69/airflowtp

As the title imply, my airflow environment cannot find the pacjage "firefox" that I installed using the image dockerfile from "docker-selenium". Because of my lack of experience on docker and airflow, I'm not able to find an answer to this question.
Could you check my docker-compose.yaml to see if I'm not doing things right ?